# Query about Operator Overloading in Python

Tags: python

I don't understand how the `+` Operator between `v1` and `v2` results in the calling of the function `add` in the code below.

```
self.a = a
self.b = b

def __str__(self):
   return 'Vector (%d, %d)' % (self.a, self.b)

def __add__(self,other):
   return Vector(self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)

v1 = Vector(2,10)
v2 = Vector(5,-2)

print v1 + v2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When the interpreter sees that you're trying to add something to a `Vector` object, it checks whether the object has a method called `__add__()`. If it does, the interpreter calls that method, passing both operands. The return value of the method is the result of the operation.

For each operator that can be overloaded there is a [magic method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) that can be implemented to perform the operation.

This explanation is simplified in the sense that it is also possible for the right-hand operand (`v2` in your example) to overload the operation. There are also special rules around in-place operator such as `+=`, and [other complications](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__coerce__).